# Linear Regression: Is there a difference in the model between using ML instead MSE?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

We know we need 4 things for building a machine learning algorithm:

1. A Dataset
2. A Model
3. A cost function
4. An optimization procedure

Taking the example of linear regression (`y = m*x +q`) we have two most common way of finding the best parameters: using `ML` or `MSE` as cost functions.

We hypotize data are `Gaussian-distributed`, using ML.

Is this assumption part of the model, also?

It it's not, why? Is it part of the cost function?

I can't see the "edge" of the model, in this case.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Dear @MATTEO , you have asked loads of question on SO and so far you have not accepted any answer! Please reward the user who gives you the best answer by clicking on the Green Correct Sign on the left side of the answer to keep SO a constructive forum!

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that the data is Gaussian-distributed is part of the model in the sense that, for Gaussian distributed data the minimal **Mean Squared Error** also yields the [maximum liklelihood solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) for the data, given the model parameters. (Common proof, you can look it up if you are interested).

So you could say that the Gaussian distribution assumption justifies the choice of least squares as the loss function.

Comment: So we can say model and cost function aren't indipendent, but the choice of the model drives the choice of the cost function, right?

Comment: Mathematically speaking, yes, different models would require a different loss function to maximize the likelihood of the optimal parameters. However, for bigger models the choice of loss function will be more practical (e.g. with respect to convergence properties).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this assumption part of the model, also?

Yes it is. The ideas of different loss functions derived from the nature of the problem, consequently the nature of the model.

`MSE` by definition calculates for the mean of the squares of the errors (error means the difference between real `y` and predicted `y`) which in its turn will be high if the data is ***not*** Gaussian-Like distributed. Just imagine a few *extreme values* among the data, what will happen to the line slope and consequently the residual error?

[image: linear_regression_with_and_without_outlier]

It is worth mentioning the assumptions of Linear Regression:

1. Linear relationship
2. **Multivariate normality**
3. No or little multicollinearity
4. No auto-correlation
5. Homoscedasticity

---

> If it's not, why? Is it part of the cost function?

As far I have seen, the assumption is not directly related to the cost function itself, rather related -as above-mentioned- to the model itself.

For example, Support Vector Machine idea is separation of classes. That’s finding out a line/ hyper-plane (in multidimensional space that separate outs classes), thus its cost function is [Hinge Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) to "maximum-margin" of classification. 
On the other hand, Logistic Regression uses [Log-Loss](http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss) (related to cross-entropy) because the model is binary and works on the probability of the output (0 or 1). And the list goes on...